# Using variables in TSQL and keep formatting in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm creating some views with a lot of references to tables in another database.

At some point the other database needs to change.

I want to make it easy for the next developer to change the scripts to use another database.

This obviously work like it should:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName 
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM AnotherDatabase.SchemaName.TableName;
```

But when I do:

```
DECLARE @DB CHAR(100)
SET @DB = 'AnotherDatabase'
GO

CREATE VIEW ViewName 
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM @DB.SchemaName.TableName;
```

I get the error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ViewName, Line 3
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@DB".

I could do something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL ...
SET @SQL = ' ... FROM ' + @DB + ' ... '
EXEC (@SQL)
```

But that goes against the purpose of making it easier for the next developer - because this dynamic SQL approach removed the formatting in SSMS.

**So my question is:** how do I make it easy for the next developer to maintain T-SQL code where he needs to swap out the database reference?

Notes:

- I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2
- The other database is on the same server.

Comment: I would suggest creating a Synonym - but this would force you to use two part object naming, rather than three part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using SQLCMD variables.  This will allow you to specify the actual database name at deployment time.  SQL Server tools (SSMS, SQLCMD, SSDT) will replace the SQLCMD variable names with the assigned string values when the script is run.  SQLCMD mode can be turned on for the current query windows from the menu option Query-->SQLCMD mode option.

```
:SETVAR OtherDatabaseName "AnotherDatabaseName"

CREATE VIEW ViewName AS
SELECT *
  FROM $(OtherDatabaseName).SchemaName.TableName;
GO
```

This approach works best when SQL objects are kept under source control.

Comment: This is a good alternative too. You may want to include something in there to handle the situation in the case that the object already exists in the database.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare variables, they only live during the execution of the statement. You can not have a variable as part of your DDL. You could create a bunch of synonyms, but I consider that over doing it a bit.

The idea that your database names are going to change over time seems a bit out of the ordinary and conceivably one-time events. However, if you do still require to have the ability to quickly change over to point to a new database, you could consider creating a light utility directly in SQL to automatically generate the views to point to the new database.

An implementation may look something like this.

**Assumptions**

- Assuming we have the below databases.
- Assuming that you prefer to have the *utility* in SQL instead of building an application to manage it.

Code:

```
create database This;
create database That;
go
```

**Configuration**

Here I'm setting up some *configuration* tables. They will do two simple things:

1. Allow you to indicate the target database name for a particular configuration.
2. Allow you to define the DDL of the view. The idea is similar to Dan Guzman's idea, where the DDL is dynamically resolved using variables. However, this approach does not use the native SQLCMD mode and instead relies on dynamic SQL.

Here are the configuration tables.

```
use This;

create table dbo.SomeToolConfig (
    ConfigId int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered,
    TargetDatabaseName varchar(128) not null);

create table dbo.SomeToolConfigView (
    ConfigId int not null
        references SomeToolConfig(ConfigId),
    ViewName varchar(128) not null,
    Sql varchar(max) not null,
    unique(ConfigId, ViewName));
```

**Setting the Configuration**

Next you set the configuration. In this case I'm setting the `TargetDatabaseName` to be `That`. The SQL that is being inserted into `SomeToolConfigView` is the DDL for the view. I'm using two *variables*, one `{{ViewName}}` and `{{TargetDatabaseName}}`. These variables are replaced with the configuration values.

```
insert SomeToolConfig (TargetDatabaseName)
    values ('That');

insert SomeToolConfigView (ConfigId, ViewName, Sql)
    values
        (scope_identity(), 'dbo.my_objects', '
create view {{ViewName}}
as
    select *
    from {{TargetDatabaseName}}.sys.objects;'),
        (scope_identity(), 'dbo.my_columns', '
create view {{ViewName}}
as
    select *
    from {{TargetDatabaseName}}.sys.columns;');
go
```

**The tool**

The tool is a stored procedure that takes a configuration identifier. Then based on that identifier if drops and recreates the views in the configuration.

The signature for the stored procedure may look something like this:

```
exec SomeTool @ConfigId;
```

Sorry -- I left out the implementation, because I have to scoot, but figured I would respond sooner than later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean with "light utility"?

Comment: @MartinCarlsson -- I added a bit more detail on what I meant. Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really cool pattern that can solve problems down the line. At this client I only have access to SQL Servers and I'm not able to execute any other application. I think I'll spend a weekend writing the "SomeTool" with the ability to handle a few other cases.